# Use Specific Private Key to Generate Certificate

Tags: c#, encryption, x509certificate, bouncycastle, x509certificate2

I am working with bouncy castle and I want to generate a specific private key instead of the random key generated.

I want to provide my own private key but the code keeps generating random keys. is there a way to specify the exact private key to use in bouncy castle?

My Code is as Below. When i check the generated certificate's public key, i get different values all the time. I need the value i specified.

In main

```
 var cb = new X509CertBuilder(suppliers, "CN=MandarinAS, OU=Scheme42, O=MandarinAS, C=GB",
                    CertStrength.Bits1024);


                   var cert = cb.MakeCertificate(pwd, "CN=Mandarin, OU=CustomerId, OU=Scheme42, O=OrgX, C=GB", 1,keypair);

                    File.WriteAllBytes("Cert.pfx", cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, pwd));


                File.WriteAllBytes("Cert.cer", cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert, pwd));
    var store = new X509Store(storeLocation);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

                var myCertificate = new X509Certificate2("Cert.pfx", "password");
                if (myCertificate.PrivateKey !

= null)
            {
                store.Close();

            }
//here i debug and compare the public key values myCertificate is always changing
```

X509CertBuilder.cs

```
public class X509CertBuilder
    {
        private const string SignatureAlgorithm = "SHA1WithRSA";
        private readonly int _strength;
        private readonly CryptoApiRandomGenerator _randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
        private readonly X509V3CertificateGenerator _certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
        private readonly SecureRandom _random;
        private readonly X509Name _issuer;
        private readonly GeneralName[] _generalNames;

        public X509CertBuilder(string[] validWithDomainNames, string issuer, CertStrength certStrength)
        {
            _random = new SecureRandom(_randomGenerator);
            _issuer = new X509Name(issuer);
            _strength = (int) certStrength;

            _generalNames = new GeneralName[validWithDomainNames.Length];
            for (var t = 0; t < validWithDomainNames.Length; t++)
            {
                _generalNames[t] = new GeneralName(new X509Name(validWithDomainNames[t]));
            }
        }

        public X509Certificate2 MakeCertificate(string password, string issuedToDomainName, int validYears, AsymmetricCipherKeyPair mykey=null)
        {
            _certificateGenerator.Reset();

            _certificateGenerator.SetSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm);
            var serialNumber = BigIntegers.CreateRandomInRange(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.ValueOf(long.MaxValue),
                _random);
            _certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNumber);

            _certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(new X509Name(issuedToDomainName));
            _certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(_issuer);

            var subjectAlternativeNames = new Asn1Encodable[_generalNames.Length + 1];
            // first subject alternative name is the same as the subject
            subjectAlternativeNames[0] = new GeneralName(new X509Name(issuedToDomainName));
            for (var t = 1; t <= _generalNames.Length; t++)
            {
                subjectAlternativeNames[t] = _generalNames[t - 1];
            }
            var subjectAlternativeNamesExtension = new DerSequence(subjectAlternativeNames);
            _certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectAlternativeName.Id, false,
                subjectAlternativeNamesExtension);

            _certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(DateTime.UtcNow.Date);
            _certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddYears(validYears));
            var keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(_random, _strength);

            var keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();


            keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
            var subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

            _certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(subjectKeyPair.Public);

            //Previouse auto key
            //var issuerKeyPair = subjectKeyPair;

            //My mykey
            var issuerKeyPair = mykey;
            var certificate = _certificateGenerator.Generate(issuerKeyPair.Private,_random);


            var store = new Pkcs12Store();
            var friendlyName = certificate.SubjectDN.ToString();
            var certificateEntry = new X509CertificateEntry(certificate);
            store.SetCertificateEntry(friendlyName, certificateEntry);
            store.SetKeyEntry(friendlyName, new AsymmetricKeyEntry(issuerKeyPair.Private), new[] {certificateEntry});

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                store.Save(stream, password.ToCharArray(), _random);
                return new X509Certificate2(stream.ToArray(), password,
                    X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Incorrectly answered for Java. The BouncyCastle C# API is not easily accessed online, but I believe what you are looking for is [`X509CertificateParser`](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/x509/X509CertificateParser.cs)

---

If you have the public key in DER format, you can simply pass the encoded `byte[]` to `java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate()` and you will get the proper `X509Certificate` as a result.

```
    private static X509Certificate formX509Certificate(byte[] encodedCertificate) throws CertificateException {
        try {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(encodedCertificate);
            return (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bais);
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            logger.error("Error converting the certificate", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Your calls to `X509CertBuilder` are generating a new certificate with a new key pair every time. If you already have the key pair generated (either from Java code or OpenSSL, etc.) just use the encoded certificate value to build the certificate object.

If you just have the key pair values but the public key is not formed into a certificate, use `SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded());`.

```
/**
     * Generates a self-signed {@link X509Certificate} suitable for use as a Certificate Authority.
     *
     * @param keyPair                 the {@link KeyPair} to generate the {@link X509Certificate} for
     * @param dn                      the distinguished name to user for the {@link X509Certificate}
     * @param signingAlgorithm        the signing algorithm to use for the {@link X509Certificate}
     * @param certificateDurationDays the duration in days for which the {@link X509Certificate} should be valid
     * @return a self-signed {@link X509Certificate} suitable for use as a Certificate Authority
     * @throws CertificateException      if there is an generating the new certificate
     */
    public static X509Certificate generateSelfSignedX509Certificate(KeyPair keyPair, String dn, String signingAlgorithm, int certificateDurationDays)
            throws CertificateException {
        try {
            ContentSigner sigGen = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(signingAlgorithm).setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME).build(keyPair.getPrivate());
            SubjectPublicKeyInfo subPubKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded());
            Date startDate = new Date();
            Date endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(certificateDurationDays));

            X509v3CertificateBuilder certBuilder = new X509v3CertificateBuilder(
                    reverseX500Name(new X500Name(dn)),
                    getUniqueSerialNumber(),
                    startDate, endDate,
                    reverseX500Name(new X500Name(dn)),
                    subPubKeyInfo);

            // Set certificate extensions
            // (1) digitalSignature extension
            certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.keyUsage, true, new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.keyEncipherment | KeyUsage.dataEncipherment
                    | KeyUsage.keyAgreement | KeyUsage.nonRepudiation | KeyUsage.cRLSign | KeyUsage.keyCertSign));

            certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints, false, new BasicConstraints(true));

            certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false, new JcaX509ExtensionUtils().createSubjectKeyIdentifier(keyPair.getPublic()));

            certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier, false, new JcaX509ExtensionUtils().createAuthorityKeyIdentifier(keyPair.getPublic()));

            // (2) extendedKeyUsage extension
            certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.extendedKeyUsage, false, new ExtendedKeyUsage(new KeyPurposeId[]{KeyPurposeId.id_kp_clientAuth, KeyPurposeId.id_kp_serverAuth}));

            // Sign the certificate
            X509CertificateHolder certificateHolder = certBuilder.build(sigGen);
            return new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME).getCertificate(certificateHolder);
        } catch (CertIOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | OperatorCreationException e) {
            throw new CertificateException(e);
        }
    }
```